# How can I spread a value across multiple rows without a cursor?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Is there an easy way to spread a value across multiple rows?

For example, my table contains

```
Type      Invoiced    Paid    Current
Charge    100         0       100
Charge    100         0       100
Charge    100         0       100
Payment   0         250       0
Payment   0          25       0
```

The data is imported this way, but I need to populate the `Current` and `Paid` columns with whatever they should be for that transaction based on the payment transactions that were also imported.

Is there an easy way to write a query to determine the balance for the `Current` column for each record?

For example, the 250 would apply 100 for the first two records and 50 to the next two, and the 25 would get applied to the last one, so the end result after updating the `Current` balance in my table should be:

```
Type      Invoiced    Paid    Current
Charge    100         100     0
Charge    100         100     0
Charge    100          75     25
Payment   0           250     0
Payment   0            25     0
```

I'd ideally like to do this with a single query instead of using a cursor to process each item individually. I've been trying to do it by using the [Row_Number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function and joining two subqueries, but I know I'm missing something here

Here was my first attempt, which resulted in getting the running total of the current balance

```
;with cte(invoiced, paid, current)
as (
    select invoiced, paid, current
        , row_number() over (order by datecreated)
    from mytable
)

select t1.invoiced, t1.paid, sum(t2.invoiced - t2.paid) as [current]
from cte as t1
join cte as t2 on t1.number = t2.number and t2.rownum <= t1.rownum
group by t1.uid, t1.number, t1.rownum
order by t1.rownum
```

Result:

```
Invoiced    Paid    Current
100         0       100
100         0       200
100         0       300
0         250       50
0          25       25
```

I'm sure there's a way to do this, but right now my brain seems on strike and is refusing to come up with a solution.

Comment: I might be wrong but afaik, you are thinking in terms of columns and SQL applies to rows. Maybe providing the data structure which is underlying your dataset could help.

Comment: Hi - "subselect" and "join": Good.  You're definitely on the right track.  "Row_number()": Bad.  Q: Is there any *column* that defines the *order*?  For example, "invoice#" or "po_date"?

Comment: @greg My underlying data set is pretty much the first example data set there, along with a few extra columns such as `DateCreated`, `AccountId`, `TransactionType`, and an Id field. My goal is to populate the `Current` field with whatever the current balance of that transaction is, based on any `Paid` transactions.

Comment: Is the given set ordered by DateCreated DESC ?

Comment: @greg Yes, but it's also ordered by a few more things due to times not being included with the dates. My actual `Row_Number` bit looks more like this: `row_number() over (partition by AccountId order by DateCreated, Invoiced desc)`. I just simplified it for the sake of this question since I didn't think it mattered

Comment: @Rachel - please also look at this link: it might help: http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx

Comment: Can you fix your first attempt query? I think it may be mismatched from different iterations. (ex. there is not invoiceamount in the cte)

Comment: @Zeph Sure, sorry about that the column names are not exactly the same :) I actually might have a solution, but still validating the numbers right now before I can say it will work or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a solution

First off, I don't need to link the Paid transactions to the Invoiced transactions, so I only need the sum of all payments

```
select accountid, sum(paid)
from mytable
where type = 'Payment'
group by accountid
```

Then I need to apply this value to each record until the running total becomes greater than the total paid.

To do this, I modified my running total query so it only sums the charges instead of summing both charges and payments

```
;with cte(id, accountid, invoiced, paid, current)
as (
    select id, accountid, invoiced, paid, current
        , row_number() over (order by datecreated)
    from mytable
    where type = 'Charge'
)

select t1.id, t1.accountid, t1.invoiced, sum(t2.invoiced) as [runningTotalOfCharges]
from cte as t1
join cte as t2 on t1.number = t2.number and t2.rownum <= t1.rownum
group by t1.id, t1.accountid, t1.invoiced
```

and joined that to the payment query, so now I have a bunch of rows containing the total payment amount, the running total of charges up until that record, and the current record's charge amount.

From there, I just needed a `CASE` statement to determine if the charge was fully paid, partially paid, or not paid at all, and use a little math to figure out the `Paid` and `Current` records

```
select charged.Id, charged.AccountId, charged.Invoiced
    -- Use Case statements to determine if this payment is fully paid, partially paid, 
    -- or not paid at all, then determine Current and Paid based on that
    , case when totalpaid - runningtotal >= 0 then invoiced 
        when invoiced > abs(totalpaid - runningtotal) then invoiced + totalpaid - runningtotal
        else 0 end as [Paid]
    , case when totalpaid - runningtotal >= 0 then 0 
        when invoiced > abs(totalpaid - runningtotal) then abs(totalpaid - runningtotal)
        else invoiced end as [Current]
from 
(
    -- Running total query from above
    select t1.id, t1.accountid, t1.invoiced, sum(t2.invoiced) as [runningtotal]
    from cte as t1
    join cte as t2 on t1.number = t2.number and t2.rownum <= t1.rownum
    group by t1.id, t1.accountid, t1.invoiced
) as charged

inner join (
    -- Total Paid query from above
    select accountid, sum(paid) as totalpaid
    from mytable
    where type = 'Payment'
    group by accountid
) as paid on charged.number = paid.number
```

And the end result is what I want. Just need to join this to the actual data table via the `Id` column, and update the `Paid` and `Current` values :)

```
Id    AccountId    Invoiced    Paid    Current
1     1            100         100     0
2     1            100         100     0
3     1            100         75      25
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate running totals and sums for the paid and current columns and then perform some math to get the current column values.  I gave it a try but got bogged down in the math to come up with the final values.  It's not an easy way, but it's a way.

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
    [TranId] INT,
    [Type] VARCHAR(10),
    [Invoiced] INT,
    [Paid] INT,
    [Current] INT,
    [SumPaid] INT,
    [SumCurrent] INT,
    [RunningPaid] INT,
    [RunningCurrent] INT
)

INSERT INTO @myTable SELECT 1, 'Charge', 100, 0, 100, null, null, null, null
INSERT INTO @myTable SELECT 2, 'Charge', 100, 0, 100, null, null, null, null
INSERT INTO @myTable SELECT 3, 'Charge', 100, 0, 100, null, null, null, null
INSERT INTO @myTable SELECT 4, 'Paid', 0, 250, 0, null, null, null, null
INSERT INTO @myTable SELECT 5, 'Paid', 0, 25, 0, null, null, null, null


UPDATE @myTable SET SumPaid = (SELECT SUM([Paid]) FROM @myTable)
UPDATE @myTable SET SumCurrent = (SELECT SUM([Current]) FROM @myTable)
UPDATE @myTable
SET 
    [RunningPaid] = full_running_total_set.[RunningPaid], 
    [RunningCurrent] = full_running_total_set.[RunningCurrent]
FROM @myTable
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        TranId1,
        SUM([Paid]) AS [RunningPaid],
        SUM([Current]) AS [RunningCurrent]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            set2.[Paid],
            set2.[Current],
            set1.[TranId] AS [TranId1],
            set2.[TranId] AS [TranId2]
        FROM @myTable set1
        INNER JOIN @myTable set2
            ON set1.[TranId] >= set2.[TranId]
    )running_total_set
    GROUP BY [TranId1]
)full_running_total_set
ON [TranId] = full_running_total_set.[TranId1]

SELECT * FROM @myTable
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up doing something very similar to that and have posted it as an answer of my own :) I ended up using a CASE statement to determine if the charge was fully paid, partially paid, or not paid at all and only needed a bit of math if the charge was partially paid.